# run node js scripts from gulp task

Tags: javascript, node.js, gulp, task

I have many js scripts in one folder (scripts/*.js). 
How to execute them all from the gulp task (instead of using 'node script.js' many times)?

something like

```
gulp.task('exec_all_scripts', function () {
  gulp.src(path.join(__dirname, './scripts/*.js'))
})
```

Comment: Gulp isn't really a script runner.  Why would you expect it's the correct tool for this job?

Comment: I dont know. I thought it was able to do with gulp

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Gulp is a *task runner*, meaning it's meant to automate sequences of commands; not run entire scripts. Instead, you can use NPM for that. I don't think there's a way to glob scripts and run them all at once, but you can set each file as its own npm script and use [`npm-run-all`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/npm-run-all) to run them:

```
{
    "name": "sample",
    "version": "0.0.1",
    "scripts": {
        "script:foo": "node foo.js",
        "script:bar": "node bar.js",
        "script:baz": "node baz.js",
        "start": "npm-run-all --parallel script:*",
    },
    "dependencies": {
        "npm-run-all": "^4.0.2"
    }
}
```

Then you can use `npm start` to run all your scripts at once.

If you really need to use gulp to run the scripts, you can use the same strategy, and then use [`gulp-run`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-run) to run the npm script with gulp.

```
var run = require('gulp-run');

// use gulp-run to start a pipeline 
gulp.task('exec_all_scripts', function() {
    return run('npm start').exec()    // run "npm start". 
        .pipe(gulp.dest('output'));      // writes results to output/echo. 
})
```

Answer (score 0):

you can export functions in your scripts/*.js and import them in gulpfile.js and call the functions in 'exec_all_scripts' task, it's easy

Answer (score 0):

You could concatinate all of the scripts into a single script and then execute it from the same task, a different task, or using a different process.  See the following NPM package: https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-concat

Here is an example:

```
var concat = require('gulp-concat');   // include package

gulp.task('exec_all_scripts', function() {
  return gulp.src(path.join(__dirname, './scripts/*.js')
    .pipe(concat('all_scripts.js'))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('./dist/'));  // assuming you had a dist folder but this could be anything
});
```